# SQL Server: How to generate a reference column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, increment

I'm relatively new on SQL and I have a doubt. I have a manufacturer table with fields ID, name, address, supplier_ref, etc. 
What I'm doing is scraping data from websites (manufacturers data), so after scraping I end up with a XML file with the scraped data i.e.:

```
<ID>2123</ID>
<name>Name</name>
<address>21 Tithebarn st</address> 
<supplier_ref>AX5145</supplier_ref>
```

The problem is that some of the manufacturers don't have a supplier_ref, so the supplier_ref field in the XML file generated comes up empty.
I need to generate one and I don't know how or at what point. The supplier_ref is VARCHAR, so it cannot be auto-increment...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, could you explain better? You have XML files with ID, name, address, sup_ref: now, what do you want to do? Save it to DB? What are you using a stored_procedure?  a c# script? Be more detailed

Comment: Yes, I'm using a stored procedure. First of all I use a FeedProcessorSystem in which I load the XML file with the scraped data, this feed processor system calls a stored procedure to save the data from the XML into a temporary table (into the DB) named TempDealer. What I have to do next is import from TempDealer to Dealership table. Then comes the problem... I can't import those that don't have a supplier_ref, I need to generate one... And it must be VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what constitutes a valid supplier reference, it's difficult to say. Generating a varchar of the right length isn't tricky, it's generating one that'll pass any downstream validation and not cause clashes with legitimate values elsewhere in the data.

If I was dealing with ISBN codes for books (as the closest I've come to this before), there's a reserved space specifically for 'private ISBNs' (can't remember the actual terminology, sorry) for internal use. You can allocate them to whatever you want with confidence that they'll never arrive on the back of an actual book from a publisher.

That's what you need to find here. It could be that the 'XX' reference space is reserved, in which case you can create 'XX0001', 'XX0002' and so on in safety - from experience I'd do that using a counting table containing just an ID field which can then be combined with constants to give the output value you want, but there's a number of ways it can be done.

Find out how the supplier references *actually* work, and this isn't too tricky in code. The difficult bit is identifying the business rules.

Comment: You could also have a flag for "I made this reference up myself" in a separate column. Then just use any simple sequence for the ones you're generating yourself, and use keys and code that pay attention to the "I made this reference up myself" column, e.g. include it in a composite unique key. That's guaranteed to avoid any clash no matter what the format of the valid supplier references.

Comment: @MattGibson Yes if there isn't a private namespace defined (or safely inferrable) in the supplier_ref spec, but I wouldn't do this if I could avoid it; the read logic would get significantly more complicated and potentially have to be replicated in multiple places, giving potential for some hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: The supplier_refs are different depending on the manufacturer. I.e.:  BMW: <manufacturersDealerId>08724</manufacturersDealerId>  VAUXHALL <manufacturersDealerId>GBN8B1</manufacturersDealerId> and a few more that tend to use 4 digit ints.. And then I have the rest of dealers that don't have a supplier_ref

Comment: OK - so they're arbitrary and presumably not fixed length if they're coming from multiple vendors? In which case you could try something like <ProductName>Sequence, which should be safe enough.

Comment: Yeah that's correct eftpotrm. I have to insert the list of vendors one by one as I go scraping. I don't know very well what you mean by <ProductName>Sequence could you explain a bit please??

Comment: If the product was called Thingy then I might set up a code in the format Thingy00001, Thingy00002 etc. Doesn't really matter what as long as it's clearly identifiable as coming from this source rather than a client ref, and is easy to increment.

Comment: Ah! I understand, I'll try that out and I'll come back to u if I struggle if you let me ;) many thanks!!